# Display item numbers with django paginator.

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-pagination

I want to display the item number with the items in a page using django paginator.

I want to display the item number in front of item in a page for example:

If i have total 15 items and my paginator code display 10 items per page 
then on first page it should display like:

```
1 item1
2 item2
etc
```

and next page it should display:

```
11 item11
12 item12
etc
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use generic django views with pagination, you have [`page_obj`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_context_data), and following will do the trick:

```
{% for object in object_list %}
   {{forloop.counter|add:page_obj.start_index }} 
{% endfor %}
```

Moreover, if starting from index 1 is critical, try this instead:

```
{% for object in object_list %}
   {{forloop.counter0|add:page_obj.start_index }} 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: NOTE: pagination starts from 1 not from 0 so your first object will start with "2" instead of "1"